# Disqus commenting system - comments are getting saved but not getting displayed after page refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, disqus

I just signed up for a disqus account to set it up on my website.

I registered my website URL as http://www.mydomain.com

The place that I'm implementing the commenting system is in

```
'/article/:post_id'
```

example: `http://mydomain.com/article/261`

In each different article ID page, I want the disqus commenting system to show. I'm currently able to post a comment, but they're not displaying when I come back to the page. They are saved as part of the overall website which I see in my disqus admin panel but they're not showing on that particular article page. 
Where do I set up the URL to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using a `disqus_identifier`